# nrpe user cant properly execute script remotely using lsof, netstat works

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, nrpe, lsof

I created a simple script for nagios to check a port on a remote server. Originally, I tried to use `lsof`.

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=$(lsof -i :8080 | grep LISTEN)

if [ -n "$RESULT" ]
  then
  echo "$RESULT"
exit 0
  else
   echo "Check application port is down"
exit 2
fi
```

On the local machine, the nagios user could run and execute the script and get the expected output. But remotely, using `check_nrpe`, I always got the else echo back

```
Check application port is down
```

Even though as I said running the script locally it worked properly

The nrpe user had all rights needed to execute the script, SELinux was in permissive mode, but I could never get it to work. So I changed the RESULT line to use `netstat`.

```
RESULT=$(netstat -anp | grep ":8080" | grep LISTEN)
```

And then I could get the expected response back using `check_nrpe` remotely. So I assume this is some sort of problem with `check_nrpe` and `lsof`. But I could never find anything in the logs.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions to get this to work right with `lsof`?

Answer (score 3):

Non-root users don't see any output from `lsof -i`. (Confirmed on Debian 8 and Cent 7, without SELinux.)

If you wanted to use this in a nagios check, you'd have to run lsof through sudo.

If sudo is configured to require a tty (might be the default on CentOS), you can do something like this:

```
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
nagios ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/lsof
```

Replace `nagios` with `nrpe` if necessary, and modify path to lsof if necessary.

Comment: I gave the nagios user sudo for lsof and called sudo in the nrpe.cfg file. I even tried RESULT=$(sudo lsof -i :8080 | grep LISTEN) in the script and it still did not work. I confirmed sudo lsof worked locally with the account, just remotely it does not.

Comment: See updated answer